# How to position a column text component in the middle of the screen in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have three vertically positioned text components and I'm trying to make the bottom text component sit directly underneath the middle text component, whilst keeping the middle text component in the centre of the screen, but I haven't been able to so far.

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKBjr.png) shows my progress so far and as you can see, the bottom text component (£1,234) is right at the bottom, rather than directly underneath the middle one (Balance).

Here is my code so far:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

function BalanceScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.accountNameHeading}>Account name:</Text>
      <Text style={styles.balanceHeading}>Balance</Text>
      <Text style={styles.balanceAmount}>£1,234</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function AccountScreen() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Account</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Balance" component={BalanceScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={AccountScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyTabs />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: 12,
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },

  accountNameHeading: {
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '250',
    color: 'red',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },

   balanceHeading: {
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '250',
    color: 'red',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },

  balanceAmount: {
    fontSize: 36,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
});
```

I've tried removing `flex` from the text components and instead adding `alignSelf: 'center'` and `justifyContent: 'center'` to the middle text component (Balance), but this hasn't worked and I [end up with this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBzpX.png).

I've added `backgroundColor` to make it easier for me to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I removed `flex: 1` from `balanceHeading` and added `flex: 1` to `balanceAmount` and [it worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj0Dt.png), so:

```
   balanceHeading: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '250',
    color: 'red',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },

  balanceAmount: {
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 36,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
```